# Getting website image URLs automatically using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, imageurl

I have several websites for property listings that I want to get images from and bring them into excel cells automatically using VBA, but I guess I first need to fetch all the image URLs whereby the separate procedure will fetch the images.

I am currently using the following procedure:

```
Sub scrapeimageurls()

Dim website as string
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim ElementCol As Object, Link As Object
Dim erow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

website = "https://ss.ge/ka/udzravi-qoneba/iyideba-4-otaxiani-bina-saburtaloze-3872071"

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = False

IE.navigate website

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to website…"
Loop

Set html = IE.document
Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("img")

For Each Link In ElementCol
erow = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(erow, 1).Value = Link.src

Next

End Sub
```

But this code brings all the unnecessary URLs for all the logos and stuff on the website, and I just want to get only the URLs of the images of the properties themselves. Is there another way to get these specific URLs?

The websites (other than the one used in the procedure) I want to get these data from are the following:

1. https://www.myhome.ge/ka/pr/11377747/iyideba-Zveli-ashenebuli-bina-vakeshi-wyneTis-qucha-3-oTaxiani
2. https://livo.ge/udzravi-qoneba/iyideba-bina/iyideba-5-otaxiani-bina-saburtaloze-349298
3. https://gethome.ge/udzravi-koneba/75955-iqideba-2-otakhiani-bina
4. https://www.myclient.ge/detail?id=61352
5. https://www.makler.ge/ka/ad/iyideba-3-othaxiani-bina-vakeshi-20000401
6. https://area.ge/ka/search?listingId=236146

Also, this is another procedure that was shared with me on the previous question like this, but this only works for the website that's in the code itself, not on the other ones.

```
Public Sub ImageLinks()

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With ie

    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "https://ss.ge/ka/udzravi-qoneba/iyideba-4-otaxiani-bina-saburtaloze-3872071"
    
    While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
    
    With .Document.querySelectorAll(".OrdinaryContainer > img")
    
        Dim i As Long
        
        For i = 1 To .length
        
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = .Item(i - 1).src
        
        Next
    
    End With
    
    .Quit
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: As you want one code to run on all those websites, your best bet would be to look at properties other than `src` for each `Link` to see if there is something that you can use to identify the images you want. Maybe the height or width of the image could be used to filter out smaller logos etc.?

Comment: I don't think that would be useful. Plus I don't know how to do it.

Comment: In order to download images from different websites, an individual code must be developed for each page to identify the desired images. This is because each web page has an individual structure. There is no universal code for such tasks. I would programme a macro with a loop that goes through all the desired URLs. Within the loop, a select case structure that calls a function that is programmed for the exact URL. For one case, you can use the procedure of QHarr that you call from the Select Case structure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68475635/importing-image-urls-from-website-using-vba

Comment: Sorry, it's a little unclear. In the `Select Case` structure you have to check if the domain is part of the url you want the pictures from. For Example, in `https://ss.ge/ka/udzravi-qoneba/iyideba-4-otaxiani-bina-saburtaloze-3872071` you must check for `https://ss.ge` because that is a part of all urls for that page. You can do those checks with `InStr()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function

Comment: @Zwenn I got it, and it works, on some websites, at least. Thank you.